# Primality test for numbers of the form $\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

This question is cross-linked with [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422712/primality-test-for-numbers-of-the-form-fracap-1a-1) and I didn't get an answer for the question.

Here is what I observed :

Inspired by Lucas-Lehmer primality test, I think I made a primality test for numbers of the form $\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$ but the test isn't perfect and there are some conditions to apply :

- $a$ must not be a perfect power otherwise you can get false positive.
- $p$ must be a prime number $\ge 3$ otherwise you can "break" the primality test and get false positive.

Let $N = \frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$

Let the sequence $S_i = 2 \cdot T_{a}(S_{i-1}/2)$ where $T_{n}(x)$ is the Chebyshev's polynomial of the first kind with $S_0 = p$.

$N$ is prime if $S_{p} \equiv 2 \cdot T_{a}(p/2)$ (mod $N$) or $S_{p} \equiv 2 \cdot T_{a-2}(p/2)$ (mod $N$)

You can run the test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtzsEKwjAMBuC74DuEndpZkQ3FQ41v4C69itBtlQ3cGraqCHt441RQ2CUhyUf4LW40HI8QN9c-QOsD5A4skOvOrghA_u66eD4jXG9_HBvq6oZlW8IeUhYZCnuiZSJXwnLV85nBgy8Fqew1FKHDhPu9qi9O8LRDUgbTmPylqFz-6Ct3E1YlyqxSqRkscPxSn4XBKUfshmHitkw_V8UZ2yD-ckn9XkZj_uhrosI35Ps68ErqJ45oU0Q=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

For the moment, I didn't find a counterexample with the two conditions.

I need help for proving it but I don't know how to start.
If you found a counterexample please tell me.

Comment: @Peter, I would like to know if it's provable and I want to know if there are counterexample. For the moment I didn't find any counterexample. I try to understand the proof of the Lucas-Lehmer and applies it for the generalized test.

Comment: Why do you expect this Primality test to work? Simply testing for a small or even moderate sized amount of numbers can be very misleading. What is the theoretical basis?

Comment: @Peter I think it is reasonable to wait for proofs of these claims before assuming true. For example this if true would provide a Primality test for rep units which is currently an open problem

Comment: Unless other information is presented, I think what is going on here is very similar to your other proposed Primality tests. Specifically you are starting with numbers that are already probable primes (strong probable primes) in $(a^p-1)/(a-1)$. Then the test via chebyshev polynomials reduces to doing a probable prime test in a different (probably in a quadratic extension field) base. Two probable prime tests together (you get one immediately from the numbers you’ve chosen as imputs) make numbers very likely to be prime. See my answer to your $(11^p-1)/10$ question.

Comment: As with all probably primes tests however, there are likely counter examples. For example I could propose a test for Primality: “let $(a^p-1)/(a-1)$ be the inputs for $p>2$ prime and $a$ not a perfect square. If $b^{\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}-1}=1\mod \frac{a^p-1}{a-1},$ for 6 different non perfect square bases $b$, then the number is prime.” Of course this is chaining multiple PRP tests and thus finding counter examples will be very very hard. But it is expected that there will be counterexamples nonetheless. This is the difficulty in proving something is prime vs very probably prime.

Comment: Final comment: the reason the Lucas Lehmer test works is because $(2^p-1)+1$ is a power of $2$ so when the Chebyshev polynomial test above reduces to a probable prime test in a quadratic extension field, we actually get that $2^p$ divides the order of all factors, proving Primality. By contrast $(a^p-1)/(a-1)+1$ is not a power of $a$ because we are dividing out by $a-1$.